# Importing module in jupyterlab notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, modulenotfounderror

Currently working through the Python Crash Course by Eric Mathes

having trouble importing module from another file as is required from page 243, [this is the error I have been receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaN6t.png)

am unsure whether to change ipynb to py or not, and is this as simple as renaming the file with .py at the end
[edit: this is a screenshot of the jupyterlab with notebook open and the file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeXtl.png)

Comment: try this `from python_settings import settings`

Comment: Could you add the folder structure and sample contents of the setting.py file

Answer (score 0):

rename the file as a settings.py . Then in the notebook that is going to use it put the code from settings import Settings.